# Asp.net MVC4: Custom paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to generate custom paging for a list.

**What I want-**

-I have a controller that returns only `10` rows from database through LINQ query with `Take()` Method.
-When view is loaded it shows 10 rows, Next thing that I am curious about is paging.

While pagesize is set to `10` rows and if it exceeds `10`; I am trying to show a list button for `next` , `Previous` 10 records from database.

I tried mapping it in this way-

**Controller**

```
public ViewResult _SeeAllLedger(LedgerModel user) {
            List<LedgerModel> ledger = null;

            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                ledger = (from u in db.LedgerTables
                          select new LedgerModel {
                              AccID = u.AccID,
                              AccountHead = u.AccountHead,
                              Place = u.Place,
                              SerialNo = Convert.ToInt32(u.SerialNumber)
                          }).ToList();

            }

            return View(ledger.Take(10)); //Returning 10 records
        }
```

**View-**

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

        <tr class="ladger-details">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccID)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccountHead)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccountHead)</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Place)
            </td>
                   </tr>
        if (Model.Count > 10) {
            <a class="btn btn-success">Next</a> //Trying to show custom button only if this state is true
        }
    }
```

As I expected it didn't work, What would be other way to map rows from LINQ query?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing many pieces to make this work correctly. Mainly, you are always taking the same 10 records. This should help get you in the correct direction.

You are going to (at least) need to know the Page Number and Page Size (10 in your case). If you want it to be more useful, a sort column and sort direction would also help.

```
ledger = (from u in db.LedgerTables
   select new LedgerModel {
        AccID = u.AccID,
        AccountHead = u.AccountHead,
        Place = u.Place,
        SerialNo = Convert.ToInt32(u.SerialNumber)
    }).Skip(pageNum * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

I use ViewBag to track the current page, page size, and total records in order to loop through and build links for all of the pages.

Comment: How? How do I get Current page? It was showing error in using `.Skip()`

Comment: Those are variables you have to create and track yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the ASP.Net PageList?

http://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedListExt.Mvc4/

Comment: Thanks for updating me, I have already worked with PagedList. Now want to customize own.